# Effective way to update a record in the database where columnname has a white space

Tags: sql, whitespace

Some of our records in the database has a white space before or after the string. I need to correct it, by simply creating an sql query. I have this proposed query below:

```
update tableA set columnname1 = trim(columnname1) where columnname1 REGEXP '^[[:blank:]]|[[:blank:]]$'

update tableA set columnname1 = trim(columnname1)

update tableA set columnname1 = trim(columnname1) where trim (columnname1) IS NOT NULL

update tableA set columnname1 = trim(columnname1) where columnname1 like ' %' or columnname1 like '% '
```

My senior doesn't accept all of them. Is there any other query to be able to update those records which has a white space?

Comment: What is the justification from the senior for the rejection?

Comment: I don't know, I even get frustrated with this.

Comment: The solutions provided are all valid. Ask him what his problem is.

Comment: One thing comes to mind: You say "a white space before **and** after the string" but your queries are all "a white space before **or** after the string". Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Ops.. sorry.. it should be before or after a string. Other data have white space before the string, others have after the string and others have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose this one

```
update tableA set columnname1 = trim(columnname1) 
 where columnname1 <> trim(columnname1)
```

Comment: Tried this query but it didnt update the record, it says update successful but the record was not changed or affected.

Comment: What happens without where clause

Comment: R u sure this is white space, may be line feed or carriage return loaded into data?

Comment: It will update all record which i think is just fine because it will just trim the white space of the string. But, my senior don't accept it, as well.

Comment: To have this work you need to check length of the columname and the trim(columname)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
update tableA set columnname1 = Rtrim(Ltrim(columnname1))
```

optionally, add

```
where columnname1 like ' %' or columnname1 like '% '
```

Comment: This isn't a programming issue then :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query.

```
UPDATE tableA
SET name = REPLACE(columnname1 , 
           SUBSTRING(columnname1 , PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']%', columnname1 ), 1), 
                  '')
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 '''''']%', columnname1 ) <> 0
```

Comment: PATINDEX is not supported in mysql.